# React-router-dom changing URL but not updating content of styled-component's ThemeProvider

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Could you help me to tell what's wrong. I'm using `react-router-dom` and when I'm trying to switch to some page -- URL is updating, but not content. If I refresh page -- content is OK

Here is my demo:
https://github.com/azat-io/react-router-dom-demo/blob/master/App.js

Here is the code:

```js
import React from 'react'
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Switch,
  Link,
} from 'react-router-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import styled, { ThemeProvider, createGlobalStyle } from 'styled-components'
import { normalize, selection } from 'polished'

import Home from 'containers/Home'
import Categories from 'containers/Categories'
import NotFound from 'containers/NotFound'

import theme from 'etc/theme'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({})

const store = createStore(rootReducer, window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ &&
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__())

const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
  ${normalize()}
  ${({ theme }) => selection({
    background: theme.primaryColor,
    color: theme.primaryContrastColor,
  })}
  a {
    display: block;
  }
`

const Container = styled.div`
  display: block;
  min-height: 100%;
`

const App = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <Container>
          <GlobalStyle />
          <menu>
            <Link to={'/'}>
              { 'to home' }
            </Link>
            <Link to={'/categories'}>
              { 'to categories' }
            </Link>
          </menu>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path={'/'} component={Home} />
            <Route path={'/categories'} component={Categories} />
            <Route component={NotFound} />
          </Switch>
        </Container>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </Router>
  </Provider>
)

render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

Comment: seems like something is blocking updates from `<Router>` so they cannot reach `<Switch>`

Comment: try w/o `<Container />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Container` Component is is not getting its children updated. So the problem comes from styled-components.

A working solution is to wrap the `<Router>` in your `<Container>` instead of the opposite... like so:

```js
const App = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Container>
        <Router>
        <React.Fragment>
          <GlobalStyle />
          <menu>
            <Link to={"/"}>{"to home"}</Link>
            <Link to={"/categories"}>{"to categories"}</Link>
          </menu>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path={"/"} component={Home} />
            <Route path={"/categories"} component={Categories} />
            <Route component={NotFound} />
          </Switch>
        </React.Fragment>
        </Router>
      </Container>
    </ThemeProvider>
  </Provider>
);
```

Another solution (untested) would be to use styled('div') instead of styled.div and keep the rest of your code unchanged.

Or one more thing (untested) to try is to replace `<Container>` by `<ContainerWrapper>` and here's its code: `const ContainerWrapper = props => <Container>{props.children}</Container>`
The reason for this is to have a stateless function that we're sure it updates on route change.

Feel free to let me know which works best in order to adjust this answer for future reference.

Comment: Hi, this solution is working but is there an explanation as to why on hard refresh, the children component gets updated but not on hot-reload?

Comment: @LiSim because the whole DOM is re-rendered on hard refresh. While when hot reloading, something from the router might be preventing from identifying the changes of styled-components children.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the explanation @Asten Mies! Was curious as to why there was a strange behaviour on the styled-component